# Disabling Socket.io heartbeats (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, socket.io, heartbeat

The [socket.io documentation](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO) mentions that heartbeats can be disabled like so:

`io.disable('heartbeats');`

Unfortunately, while this seems to stop the hearbeats from being sent, the clients still disconnect when they are not sending hearbeats.

The following does not function either:

`io.set('heartbeats', false);`

I have tried setting some intervals to 0, without success:

```
io.set('heartbeat timeout', 0);
io.set('heartbeat interval', 0);
```

Any suggestions on what might properly disable heartbeats?

Comment: Note that my question is from Sep 8 '11, the disable mechanic may have been fixed by now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is

```
io.disable('heartbeats');
```

Tested successfully on socket.io v0.8.7

Without disabling

```
debug - emitting heartbeat for client 299833185260419425
debug - websocket writing 2::
debug - set heartbeat timeout for client 299833185260419425
debug - got heartbeat packet
debug - cleared heartbeat timeout for client 299833185260419425
debug - set heartbeat interval for client 299833185260419425
```

With disabling

debug - client authorized

```
info  - handshake authorized 1205975980561506547
debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/1205975980561506547
debug - client authorized for 
debug - websocket writing 1::
debug - websocket writing 5:::{"name":"news","args":[{"hello":"foo"}]}
```

Comment: just stumbled upon this. Was Tom just not sure it was working? I don't see how this is different from what he said he was trying to make work with no effect.

Comment: This was causing errors with the latest 0.9.X for me, but after switching socket.io to 0.8.7 as you mentioned it works... I'm assuming it is a bug somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

There is something wrong with heartbeats. I have latest socket.io and node 0.6.X

```
   info  - socket.io started
   debug - client authorized
   info  - handshake authorized 734447051478827620
   debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/734447051478827620
   debug - client authorized for
   debug - websocket writing 1::
   debug - websocket writing 5:::{"name":"hello"}
   info  - transport end (socket end)
   debug - set close timeout for client 734447051478827620
   debug - cleared close timeout for client 734447051478827620
   debug - discarding transport

// server code
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8080);
io.disable('heartbeats');

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('hello');
});
```

Client is disconnected right after connection.

Answer (score 1):

Set the log level of socket.io, with log level 2 we wont see all the heartbeats of each socket but only the handshakes and disconnections

> io.set('log level', 2);